# Storing ArrayList in onSavedInstanceState

Tags: android, mobile, android-listview

I'm running an asynctask in a Fragment class and populating a `ListView` with the result. However I only run this asynctask the first time this fragment is instantiated.

How do I store the the `ArrayList` of objects created in the asynctask in `onSavedInstance` so I can retrieve them later?

I tried using `putParcelableArrayList` but I still get a `NullPointerException` when I try to retrieve it.

Thanks for your help

Stops:

```
    public class Stops implements Parcelable{

private String station_name;
private ArrayList<Stops> stopTitles;

public Stops()
{

}

public Stops(Parcel source)
{
    station_name = source.readString();
    source.readTypedList(stopTitles, Stops.CREATOR);
}

public String getStation_name() {
    return station_name;
}

public void setStation_name(String station_name) {
    this.station_name = station_name;
}

public void setStopTitles(ArrayList<Stops> stopTitles) {
    this.stopTitles = stopTitles;
}

public ArrayList<Stops> getStopTitles() {
    return stopTitles;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return station_name;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dest.writeString(station_name);
    dest.writeList(stopTitles);
}

 public static final Parcelable.Creator<Stops> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Stops>() {

        @Override
        public Stops createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Stops(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Stops[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Stops[size];
        }
 };
```

}

Comment: Show your code for whatever `stopTitles` is and the objects it contains.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made a Parcelable implementation of the Object you are holding in the ArrayList? If the object is not parcelable you cannot pass the list to `onSavedInstance` example code:

```
        public class ParcelableObject implements Parcelable {
        String field;
            @Override
            public int describeContents() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
                dest.writeValue(field);         
            }

            public static final Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableObject> CREATOR =
                 new Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableObject>() {

                public ParcelableObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                    ParcelableObject obj = new ParcelableObject();
                    obj.readFromParcel(in)
                    return obj;
                }

                public ParcelableObject[] newArray(int size) {
                     return new ParcelableObject[size];
                }
           };

        private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
               field = in.readString()
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have done that. In the writeToParcel method is this correct?

Comment: What kind of Objects are you storing in the list? Are they Parcelable?

Comment: It's a custom object. I'm not to sure what you mean if there parcelable, i'm still getting my head around the parcelable interface, only came accross it today

Comment: I'm starting to understand the parcelable interface more now but I'm still getting the NullPointerException